# How to find mean of a group of values based on unique ID in a new column?

Tags: pandas

I want to create a new column 'DataMean' which finds the mean of a set of values in 'Data' column grouped by their ID. This is the dataframe I currently have:

```
ID  Data
0   NaN
0   NaN
0   NaN
0   NaN
1   34
1   36
0   NaN
0   NaN
2   12
0   NaN
0   NaN
3   23
3   16
0   NaN
0   NaN
4   23
4   11
4   2
4   8
```

I want my final output to look like the following. It should not calculate mean if there NaN in Data value and should display mean value only once if ID is repeated. Could anyone guide me on how to display output in such a way?

```
ID Data MeanData
0   NaN NaN
0   NaN NaN
0   NaN NaN
0   NaN NaN
1   34  35
1   36  NaN
0   NaN NaN
0   NaN NaN
2   12  12
0   NaN NaN
0   NaN NaN
3   23  19.5
3   16  NaN
0   NaN NaN
0   NaN NaN
4   23  11
4   11  NaN
4   2   NaN
4   8   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
df.loc[df.groupby('ID').head(1).index,'MeanData']=df.groupby('ID').Data.transform('mean')
df
    ID  Data  MeanData
0    0   NaN       NaN
1    0   NaN       NaN
2    0   NaN       NaN
3    0   NaN       NaN
4    1  34.0      35.0
5    1  36.0       NaN
6    0   NaN       NaN
7    0   NaN       NaN
8    2  12.0      12.0
9    0   NaN       NaN
10   0   NaN       NaN
11   3  23.0      19.5
12   3  16.0       NaN
13   0   NaN       NaN
14   0   NaN       NaN
15   4  23.0      11.0
16   4  11.0       NaN
17   4   2.0       NaN
18   4   8.0       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat similar to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682203/create-a-new-id-column-based-on-conditions-in-other-column-using-pandas/54682408#54682408). Use the same grouping, but calculate a mean and assign where it's not duplicated:

```
s = df.Data.isnull().cumsum().where(df.Data.notnull())
df['MeanData'] = df.groupby(s).Data.transform('mean').where(~df.ID.duplicated())
```

#### Output `df`:

```
    ID  Data  MeanData
0    0   NaN       NaN
1    0   NaN       NaN
2    0   NaN       NaN
3    0   NaN       NaN
4    1  34.0      35.0
5    1  36.0       NaN
6    0   NaN       NaN
7    0   NaN       NaN
8    2  12.0      12.0
9    0   NaN       NaN
10   0   NaN       NaN
11   3  23.0      19.5
12   3  16.0       NaN
13   0   NaN       NaN
14   0   NaN       NaN
15   4  23.0      11.0
16   4  11.0       NaN
17   4   2.0       NaN
18   4   8.0       NaN
```